# In a simple jquery slide show, my class gets to the end of the images and then falls off the edge of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom, slideshow

I'm working on my mobile portfolio (http://lehuagray.com/mobile). Right now a user can flip forward and backward through my images by either sliding or using the buttons. As the user flips, the class .main is removed from their current image and transferred to either the previous or next image. But if the user flips backwards from the first slide or forward from the last slide, .main doesn't have a target to be transferred to. It falls off the edge, and the slide show ceases to function.

The HTML is just a series of divs inside a container. The CSS is probably totally inconsequential except maybe that I had to use z-index to reverse the order of the slide layers (which are absolutely positioned and stacked). Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4b8S/4/. It doesn't matter what the events are, the problem isn't in the events, so I gave the jsfiddle some buttons for ease.

Here is my jQuery code it it's most basic, everything else is just a variation on this:

```
$( "#rolodexnarrow" ).bind( "swipeleft", function(event) {
 $( this ).hide("blind", function() {
 $ ( this ).removeClass("main").next().addClass("main")
  });
});
$( "#rolodexnarrow" ).bind( "swiperight", function(event) {
  $ ( this ).removeClass("main").prev().addClass("main");
  $( this ).prev().show("blind");
});
```

I've tried an if statement:

```
$( "#rolodexnarrow" ).bind( "swipedown", function(event) {
  $( ".main" ).prev().show("blind");    
  if ( $(".main").is("#slide1") == false ){
     $ ( ".main" ).removeClass("main").prev().addClass("main");
  }
});
```

Counter-intuitively (to me at least), this just makes the first and last slides no longer show/hide and no longer receive the .main class, so we get stuck with the second and second-to-last slides up. I have also tried an if statement using (":first"). This is obviously a pretty simple slide show, I'm sure there is a simple solution. I'm sure, also, that this is something that everyone else already knows how to fix but I can't find anything about it since I'm not even really sure what to search for.

Noe: The swipe is a touch interface and barely works on a mouse, especially since everything is linked to lightboxes. If you use a touch device, it doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, it's pretty long to read and doesn't allow us to experiment. You should create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce the problem. You'll be amazed by both the quality and the number of answers you get after that.

Comment: k, I played with your site a bit (and I don't like the present interface, was pretty difficult to understand what is going on; there is a image slideshow that starts if I click in the main region and it took me some time to figure out that you have buttons to flip on and flip back but let's leave that aside). Can you not just disable the respective buttons when you reach the first or last slide?

Comment: Also, what events are you really after - swipe-left and right or swipe-up and down? The code you have provided has them both.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4b8S/. It doesn't matter what the events are, the problem isn't in the events, so I made the events for the fiddle click and double click. I'm after both swipe left/right and up/down and also click (on the buttons), because I want it to work regardless of which way the user intuitively interacts. The swipe is a touch interface and barely works on a mouse, especially since everything is linked to lightboxes, so I'm not surprised that the interface was confusing and difficult. If you use a touch device, it doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Yeah, debugging on a touch device is a problem. So, I keep using my laptop and desktop. Let me look at you fiddle. In the meanwhile, you have not answered my question.

Comment: The answer is yes and yes. I am after both swipe left-right and swipe up/down, and button click as well. If it doesn't work to test if the slide is last/first with an if statement, how would I tell it when to disable the buttons? And then how would I reenable them? I added buttons to the js fiddle, click and dblclick were too confusing: http://jsfiddle.net/v4b8S/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/v4b8S/6/

Here is the updated JS code:

```
$( ".container" ).bind( "click", function(event) {
    if(!$(".main").is("#slide4")) {
      $( ".main" ).hide("blind", function() {
        $ ( this ).removeClass("main").next().addClass("main");
      });
    }
});
$(".container").on( "dblclick", function(event) {
    if( !$(".main").is("#slide1")) {
        $(".main").prev().show("blind");
        $(".main").removeClass("main").prev().addClass("main");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE1:**

Also, read jquery's [dblclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event and its handling. In particular, notice that adding handlers for both the click and the dblclick event are not suggested since which one will be triggered first is highly browser and machine dependent. I guess that'll not be a problem for your usecase since you are going to change it to swipe events. (For me, I had to manually trigger the dblclick event using browser console.)

**UPDATE2:**

The dblclick event handler is also working fine now. I had to change the order of things there.

**UPDATE3:**

I didn't see your new fiddle till now. Basically it's the same code as above but is activated on the click of the forward and backward buttons.

```js
/*code with if statement, if you want to play with that
$( ".forward" ).bind( "click", function() {
  if ( $(".main").is("#slide4") == false ){
    $( ".main" ).hide("blind", function() {
      $ ( this ).removeClass("main").next().addClass("main")
    });
  }
});
$( ".backward" ).bind( "click", function() {
    $( ".main" ).prev().show("blind");    
    if ( $(".main").is("#slide1") == false ){
       $ ( ".main" ).removeClass("main").prev().addClass("main");
    }
});
*/

//simple code
$(".forward").click(function() {
  if (!$(".main").is("#slide4")) {
    $(".main").hide("blind", function() {
      $(this).removeClass("main").next().addClass("main");
    });
  }
});

$(".backward").click(function() {
  if (!$(".main").is("#slide1")) {
    $(".main").prev().show("blind");
    $(".main").removeClass("main").prev().addClass("main");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#slide1 {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 5;
}
#slide2 {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 4;
}
#slide3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 3;
}
#slide4 {
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 2;
}
.button {
  padding: 14px 7px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.main {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide main" id="slide1"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide2"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide3"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide4"></div>
</div>
<div class="forward button">forward</div>
<div class="backward button">backward</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying it now!

Comment: @user2270306 - I have updated the code and the link to fiddle. Please have a look.

Comment: The forward-flipping code you gave me works perfectly, and with some adjustments the backwards-flipping code works on JSfiddle, but on my web site it does not, even with adjustments. I got the backward code working on jsfiddle by changing $this to .main and switching the order. Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4b8S/8/. I updated the code on my website too, but if you go you will see that flipping backwards is impossible (you can either use the buttons of swipe up/down). Both the class .main disappears AND the show doesn't run. Any ideas? It isn't a complicated website...

Comment: @user2270306 - it's pretty late for me now. Why don't you go ahead with this code and I assure you that we'll get it working tomorrow. In the meanwhile, I'll be glad if you accepted this answer. The discussion thread has anyways become very long.

Comment: BTW, your UI is looking pretty good now! For some reason, I am unable to move past the 4th slide. Looks like you are actively working on the site right now.

Comment: So the final code that worked on my website for flipping backwards was:
`    $(".backward").bind( "click", function(event) {
        if( !$(".main").is("#slide1")) {
            $(".main").removeClass("main").prev().addClass("main").show("blind");
        }
    });`

Success!